# NServiceBus Gateway url not accessible in Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, nservicebus, gateway

I've setup a demo NSB Gateway pretty much based on the samples. all working fine when running from visual studio. msg send from SiteA being received on SiteB.

However after I host SiteB in my local Windows Service (NServiceBus.Host.exe /install), I've noticed that SiteB's url is no longer accessible (ie. `http://localhost:25899/SiteB`) hence msg sent from SiteA all went into error queue.

Help would be apprecaited!

Answer (score 0):

I've got it sorted!

when installing on the server i just need to add "NServiceBus.Lite NServiceBus.MultiSite" to the command line.

and it's all working as intended.